# Как изменяются координаты в зависимости от угла поворота объекта?

Tags: python, алгоритм, геометрия

Проблема в том, чтобы в зависимости от угла поворота, объект двигался в соответствующем направлении. Пытался сделать, получил такой ужас(python):

```
from graphics import *
from pygame.locals import *
import time
import pygame

FPS = 60
W = 700  # ширина экрана
H = 300  # высота экрана
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE = (0, 70, 225)

pygame.init()
sc = pygame.display.set_mode((W, H))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# координаты и радиус круга
x = W // 2
y = H // 2
rotatex = 0
r = 50

while 1:
    sc.fill(WHITE)

    car = pygame.image.load('car.png')
    car_rect = car.get_rect(center=(x, y))
    car = pygame.transform.rotate(car, rotatex)
    sc.blit(car, car_rect)  
    pygame.display.update()
    # pygame.draw.circle(sc, BLUE, (x, y), r)

    pygame.display.update()

    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_LEFT]:
        rotatex += 2
        # car = pygame.transform.rotate(car, rotatex)
        # car_rect = car.get_rect(center=(x, y))
        # sc.blit(car, car_rect)
        # pygame.display.update()

    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_RIGHT]:
        rotatex -= 2
        # car = pygame.transform.rotate(car, rotatex)
        # # x += 1
        # car_rect = car.get_rect(center=(x, y))
        # sc.blit(car, car_rect)
        # pygame.display.update()

    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_UP]:
        y -= 1
        y += rotatex/45 
        x -= rotatex/45

    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_DOWN]:
        y += 1
        x += rotatex/45
    clock.tick(FPS)
    pygame.event.pump()
    if rotatex >= 180:
        rotatex = 0
```

Крутится, но в соответствующем направлении двигается вперед не везде. Какая формула должна быть для изменения x и y? Код мне не нужен, просто формула. В Google уже искал.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по значениям, `rotatex` - это угол поворота в градусах. Для правильного движения в заданном направлении нужно иметь x- и y- компоненты единичного вектора направления, которые выражаются через cos и sin угла.

```
dx = cos(radians(rotatex))
dy = sin(radians(rotatex))
```

Для движения нужна амплитуда скорости V (к которой подбирается коэффициент для данного разрешения и т.п.), тогда компоненты скорости

```
vx = V * dx
vy = V * dy
```

Для движения вперёд

```
y += vy 
x += vx
```

Если требуется разгон, меняем V и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

@MBo в чем то прав, но его формулы работали частично. Я же еще поискал, и в глуши YouTube отыскал формулу, которая действительно работала. С моим кодом она выглядит вот так:

```
    x = x + V * math.cos(math.radians(270-rotatex)) # для езды вперед
    y = y + V * math.sin(math.radians(270-rotatex))

    x = x - V * math.cos(math.radians(270-rotatex)) # для езды назад
    y = y - V * math.sin(math.radians(270-rotatex))
```

Comment: Ну с чего бы мой код работал частично, если кода и не было. А то, что у Вас написано - связано с определением системы координат, в которой угол, видимо, отсчитывается от вертикального направления, а ось X всё-таки горизонтальна

Comment: @MBo Ну я воспользовался вашими формулами(хорошо, не кодом) и объект очень криво двигался.

Comment: @MBo Ну все равно если хорошо подумать куда его вставлять, то все будет верно. Поэтому ваш ответ верен.

Comment: @VerNick, тут чистая математика. Если вы вычитаете из 270 градусов, вы для косинуса меняете знак на противоположный, а для синуса ничего не делаете. Ваши верхние две формулы превращаются в `x - V * cos(radiands(rotatex))` и `y + V * sin(radians(rotates))`. Минус и плюс в данном случае подсказывают, что у вас система координат зеркально отражена по сравнению с той, для которой выведены оригинальные формулы. В оригинале предполагается, что ось *Ox* идёт слева направо, ось *Oy* снизу вверх, углы отсчитываются от оси *Ox*.

Comment: @VerNick Это не проблема, и не беда. Это повод для открывания учебника и ознакомления с материалом. Синусы и косинусы это седьмой класс. Если вы младше, то у вас есть шанс освоить материал раньше одноклассников. Если старше, повторите. Без тригонометрии в компьютерной графике очень грустно.